# The parameter URL was not updated after changing config.toml in gitlab-runner container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to configure and execute GitLab CI jobs, that is why I have two Docker containers:

- `gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest`
  -`gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`

Now every gitlab CI build fails with the error:

> Running with gitlab-runner 12.3.0 (a8a019e0) on sonar-runner rRZ6XQ2Y
>       Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
>       Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
>       Using docker image sha256:cc0abc535e36a7e for alpine:latest ...
>       Running on runner-rRZ6XQ2Y-project-2-concurrent-0 via pc-user...
>
> Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
>       Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/sonar-gitlab-kotlin/.git/
>       fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@localhost/root/sonar-gitlab-kotlin.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/root/sonar-gitlab-kotlin/.git/

In order to fix the problem

1. I've changed parameter URL in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`
2. Inside of gitlab-cunner container: `root@pc-user:/# gitlab-runner restart`
3. `$ docker restart gitlab-runner`

so now I have:

```
root@pc-user:/# gitlab-runner list
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=45 revision=a8a019e0 version=12.3.0
Listing configured runners                          ConfigFile=/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
sonar-runner                                        Executor=docker Token=rRZ6XQ2YWXxxxxxxx URL=http://192.168.74.12/
```

However, I'm still getting the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@**localhost**/root/sonar-gitlab-kotlin.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

But I expected to have

```
http://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@**192.168.74.12**/root/sonar-gitlab-kotlin.git/
```

Could you please clarify: I'm wrong with my expectation or the parameter should changed.